# appveyor matrix vs tox matrix

Tags: python, testing, appveyor, tox

I've found many references to use [tox](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) and a CI server, like [appveyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) for Python testing. However, the dependency matrices have confused me. It seems redundant for me and I don't know why to use both, like it acts in several examples. ([Appveyor's docs](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/lang/python/), or an [example repo](https://github.com/awslabs/pipeformer/blob/master/appveyor.yml).)

I mean, I will list the same environment-settings under `environment -> matrix` in `appveyor.yml` as in `envlist` in the `tox.ini`.

Is it really redundant? Then why we use both matrices?

Answer (score 1):

One matrix is for AppVeyor, another (well, it's the list of environments) is for `tox`. They are to some extend redundant but there is no way to avoid that redundancy because neither `tox` nor AppVeyor could read each other config files.

Comment: Thanks, but I still skeptical of using both matrices. Appveyor has some problems around [deploying using matrices](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/2725-only-deploy-after-all-parallel-testing-branches-succeed). So I will use the only tox-matrices, and I will list all of `testenv` under `envlist`.